# How can I use realmResults object

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

Where does form of realmResults Array when selecting realm data exist?
How can I use realmResults ???

realmResults >> realmArray[0][1], realmArray[1][3].....

textView1.text = realmArray[0][0]<< This is my wish T^T

plz help me..;)

```
if (readingId != null) {
        val readingResult = realm.where<ReadingTable>()
            .equalTo("id_reading", readingId)
        var realmList = arrayOf(readingResult)
        println(realmList[1])


    }
```

Comment: Considering `ReadingTable`'s schema is unknown, no one can answer this question.